# It is possible to show page in own activity in Xamarin.Forms on Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I want to navigate between pages be starting and finishing new activity for any new page and show this page in own activity. How to achieve this behavior?

Comment: Yes, if you use Xamarin.Forms "Embedding",  basically you are using the Android Activity lifecycle and embedding a ContentPage on each Activity. Of course you are giving up all the helpful features of having a Forms' `Application` floating around. Personally at that point, you might want to look at just using Xamarin.Android Native for the UI and use C# as the common "sharable" code in the app logic backend.

Comment: Could it work ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is Yes,you could look at [Native Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/native-forms).

For ios:

in ios project `AppDelegate`

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
{
    Forms.Init();

   ...

    UIViewController mainPage = new NotesPage().CreateViewController();
    mainPage.Title = "Notes";

    _navigation = new AppNavigationController(mainPage);
    _window.RootViewController = _navigation;
    _window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

    return true;
}
```

For Android:

in Android project your activity ,it convert your page to a fragment,and then you could fill it in your activity:

```
Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment mainPage = new NotesPage().CreateSupportFragment(this);
SupportFragmentManager
        .BeginTransaction()
        .Replace(Resource.Id.fragment_frame_layout, mainPage)
        .Commit();
```

Answer (score -2):

On Android Xamarin.Forms navigate among pages by using Fragments.

If you don't like it you may fork Xamarin.Forms and change the code to work the way you want it to work: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms

This will make some packages incompatible with your fork of Xamarin.Forms, which you may need to take under consideration if you intend to use them.

Also if you consider the required time and knowledge this is non-trivial. It is highly unlikely that someone will do that job instead of you and provide you with the plug-in solution.